# unable to deploy spring/hibernate/GWT application on jboss

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gwt, jboss

I am trying to deploy a spring/hibernate/gwt application on jboss eap 6.4.0. My versions are

```
spring - 4.2.2.FINAL
hibernate - 5.0.3
gwt - 2.7
```

I am able to run and deploy the application on tomcat and internal jetty provided by GWT, but when I am trying to deploy the application on jboss I am getting following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ashish/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) [hibernate-core-5.0.3.Final.jar:5.0.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401) [spring-orm-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) [spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 36 more
```

and it is not creating the application context. I have been through all the related stackoverflow question and also added jboss-logging to my maven configuration. I can see jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final in the lib folder of my war file as well, but I am not sure why am I getting this error. All the help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm on my mobile so I cannot check it my self. Look up in Grepcode to see in which library and which version is CoreMessageLoader#debugf defined.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss is shipped along with hibernate library. See the link below to check the hibernate version which is shipped with different versions of JBoss.

https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673

You are using a later version (5.X) whereas JBoss has 4.x version (in EAP 6.4.0). I think hibernate jar in jboss lib is loaded first and hence you are getting the error.

One solution could be to delete the hibernate jar from jboss lib and then try.

Comment: so the question would be how to delete those jars

Comment: JBoss EAP is a module based system. You will have to use add/remove module commands to remove 4.x hibernate module.